# HTML element attributes dynamic assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have the following HTML code:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <FORM>
            <div name="container" id="setup">
                <div name="element 1" id="element 1"> 
                    <input type="button" value="xxx" name="button 1" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

And I would like to achieve the following:

Assign the button value whatever the parent node id is ("element 1" in this case) instead of static "xxx". Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set button an ID
**There should be not spacing between id and name is html**
e.g.

```
<div name="element1" id="element1"> 
     <input type="button" value="xxx" name="button1" id=button1/>
</div>
```

Javascript =>

```
    var button = document.getElementById('button1');
    var parentId = button.parentNode.id;
    button.setAttribute('value',parentId);
```

**You can also do this on a particular event or as you wish.**

**[Check the Code Snippet Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BWtjm/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="button"]').val(function(){
  return this.parent.id;
});
```

Something like that presumably?

Comment: Thanks, I am fairly new to web design, so is it javascript or jquery? Where should I put it in the code? Also if I clone "element 1" and give it  different id will your code kick in for that cloned element as well? Thanks.